# nestedsortable.js toarray not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, nested-sortable

This is my first use of nestedsortable.js in a custom cms creation with codeigniter, So I use it with Codeigniter php framework.
I have an ordered and nested list(for order pages) and I need to convert this list to array with 'toArray' but it's not working
the error message: uncaught typeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined
this is my js code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post('<?=base_url("index.php/admin/pages/order_ajax"); ?>',{},function(data){
        $('#orderResult').html(data);
    });
    $('#save').click(function(){
        oSortable = $('.sortable').nestedSortable('toArray');
        $.post('<?=base_url("index.php/admin/pages/order_ajax"); ?>',{sortable:oSortable},function(data){
            $('#orderResult').html(data);
        });
    });

});
```

except that everything is good, so I need your help

Comment: Couldn't you use: `oSortable = $('.sortable').get();`

Comment: not working, the toarray get the list as a nested array.I need this array to continue the other proccesses

Comment: Maybe you should provide what you get and what you expect to get...

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. The solution is simple. You need set id for your li elements.

```
<li id="list_1"> etc...
```

Because without a set id, element returns "undefined" and it throws an error. Function "match" needs string.